# How to check the validity of the required argument in Moose constructor?

Tags: perl, moose

This is *sure* very simple question, but i'm still learning and not found the answer.

Need check the validity of the supplied (required) argument to Moose object constructor, e.g. like in the next example:

```
use 5.016;
use warnings;

package My {
    use Moose;
    has 'mydir' => (
        is          => 'ro',
        isa         => 'Str',
        required    => 1,
    );
}

use File::Path qw(remove_tree);
package main {
    my @dirs = qw(./d1 ./d2);

    #ensure no one dir exists
    remove_tree($_) for ( @dirs );

    #create the first dir
    mkdir $dirs[0] or die;

    foreach my $dir( @dirs ) {
        my $m = My->new( mydir=>$dir );
        say "$dir ", defined($m) ? "" : "NOT", " ok";
    }
}
```

The question is: what i should add to the `My` package to ensure create the `My` object **only if** the supplied `mydir` path exists? So somewhere need add the test `if -d ...` .

How to define the attribute `mydir` with validity check?

Wanted result of the main program:

```
./d1 ok
./d2 NOT ok
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a subtype with a [type constraint](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/Moose-2.1005/lib/Moose/Manual/Types.pod#SUBTYPES).

The syntactic sugar for working with this is provided by [Moose::Util::TypeConstraints](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/Moose-2.1005/lib/Moose/Util/TypeConstraints.pm).

```
package My;
use 5.16.0;

use Moose;
use Moose::Util::TypeConstraints; # provides sugar below

subtype 'ExistingDir' => (
    as 'Str',
    where { -d $_ },
    message { 'The directory does not exist' }
    );

has 'mydir' => (
        is          => 'ro',
        isa         => 'ExistingDir',
        required    => 1,
    );

package main;

my $foo = My->new(mydir => 'perl'); # exists
say $foo->mydir();

my $bar = My->new(mydir => 'perlXXX'); # does not exist, so dies here...
```

outputs:

```
>mkdir perl
>perl foo.pl

perl
Attribute (mydir) does not pass the type constraint because: The directory does not exist at ...
```

Comment: Further to that, there are various pre-written type constraints for this sort of thing on CPAN, such as `AbsDir` in [Types::Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/module/Types::Path::Tiny).